# is there a more succint way to evaluate something explicitly in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to learn prolog and as an exercise I tried implementing the [Extended euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm); what exactly I'm doing isn't particularly important since I'm only curious about a specific syntax thing, but here's the full code:

```
e_gcd(A, B, Lx, Ly) :-
    e_gcd(A, B, 0, 0, 1, 0, Lx, Ly).

e_gcd(_, 0, _, _, LX, LY, LX, LY).

e_gcd(A, B, X, Y, LX, LY, FX, FY) :-
    Q is A // B,
    M is A mod B,
    e_gcd(B, M, LX-Q*X, LY-Q*Y, X, Y, FX, FY).
```

I need to do `M is A mod B` and then `e_gcd(B, M, LX-Q*X, LY-Q*Y, X, Y, FX, FY).` because otherwise I get a zero division error later, since I fall through the check `e_gcd(_, 0, _, _, LX, LY, LX, LY).`
My question is this: is there a way to evaluate `A mod B` without storing it in `M`? I would like to avoid naming things I'm using in the very next line and nowhere else, if possible (I'm fine with `Q` since I need to use it two times).

Comment: Note that for `?-e_gcd(1,1,1,1).`, you still get a zero division error, but that is maybe not important.

Comment: @tiffi thanks for spotting that, I'll fix it (though for what I'm doing I shouldn't ever get that)

Comment: Looking at your code, I get the impression that you are just not ready to accept that Prolog has no functions. It has terms and (fully instantiated) arithmetic terms are evaluated used in specific contexts - like e.g. on the right side of the `is/2`-predicate.

Comment: @tiffi Ig I'm not thinking the right way for prolog. I'll look into it some more, do you have advice for what resources would be good?

Comment: First of all, it is pretty rare for a language not to have functions, so it is normal to expect them. Second, functions are usually particularly missed in arithmetic puzzles, so you just need to accept that Prolog will feel more clumsy in such cases. As for a resource - my recommendation would be Clocksin/Mellish (https://www.springer.com/gp/book)./9783540006787

Comment: Just as an aside: even in languages that provide functions, it is not always the best way to use as little variables as possible - sometimes it is worth to use a variable or line more, because it enhances readability and debugability. The only way to get around using a ton of variables in Prolog is by using terms instead of numbers - that's what you have done in some places, while in others not. As you have already realized with the need to check for a zero value, that has its disadvantages.

Comment: Conclusion: don't do it - accept Prolog as it is. It may be a bit clumsy for arithmetic puzzles, but it is super-short and powerful for others. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to evaluate `A mod B` right away. But note that an unevaluated expression of the form `A mod B` will never unify with a constant like `0`, so you need to evaluate your argument term in the first clause if you want to compare it to 0.

So you can write this, but it will not be shorter than what you had:

```
e_gcd(_, B, _, _, LX, LY, LX, LY) :-
    B =:= 0.  % force evaluation of the term B to a number, then compare

e_gcd(A, B, X, Y, LX, LY, FX, FY) :-
    B =/= 0,
    Q is A // B,
    e_gcd(B, A mod B, LX-Q*X, LY-Q*Y, X, Y, FX, FY).
```